# Template Solution(s) that are not PHP include

Tags: javascript, php, templates, handlebars.js, slim

I currently have an application that loads the html header, navigation, and footer information into an html page using separate php includes.

I am trying to re-design the application so that it no longer is dependent upon php includes (so that I can port it to PhoneGap).  I have been scouring for a solution that would allow me to get the same templating functionality, while shifting the php scripts solely to the server.

I have looked at a number of the Javascript Template Frameworks - ractive, moustache, handlebars, etc.  But most of those seem only data focused - which is great for that purpose, and I may use one for later.  But I am looking for something to provide the bones, not the attributes.  Also, each of those seems to have routing/url/seo limitations.

I have also tried some of the frameworks like Meteor, Ember, Express, and Sails but they will require a lot of additional coding to get to the same functionality I currently have - but they have the ability to define application level templating/includes.  Slim Framework seems to be closest (and maybe coupling it with Twig ), but before I commit I wanted to get some feedback/option.

Is there a better way to do this??  And if so with what?  And maybe even how??  Thanks all in advance for your feedback!

Comment: Use Twig.  It's great, and Slim even has a library to support it: https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Views

Comment: Thank you for the comment!  I was looking at Twig, but can you use Twig with Phonegap?  I thought that Phonegap did not support PHP pages?

Comment: Php and js frameworks aren't mutually exclusive.  You can generate your html fragments with Twig, hook them up to urls with Slim, and then load them into your dom with ajax and your js templating framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through a number of the solutions, I feel that using jquery with handlebars.  will actually be the best solution.  It does not allow me to do exactly what I'd like to do, but it is close.

I will keep the module pages as separate html files in a templates folder and then inject the moustache modules into the container page using jquery ajax and/or .load.